# calling sybase view from php using fatfreeframework

Tags: php, sybase, fat-free-framework

I'm having a devil of a time calling a sybase stored procedure from php using fat free. This is the call I'm trying to make. This actually a view not a stored procedure my bad

```
$results = $this->cernerdb->exec( "DECLARE @EOM DATE, 
@BOM DATE SELECT @BOM = DATE(20170401) SELECT @EOM = DATE(20170430) 
SELECT * FROM vPFS_CERNER_EOM_5A" );
```

This returns -1.

If I take the exact same command and exec it using sqsh there are no problems.

```
sqsh -Sproduction  -Uviewonly -Pnoharm  -w 5000 -s ":::"  -L 
datetime='%Y-%m-%d' -L BOM=$BOM -L EOM=$EOM -C 'DECLARE @EOM DATE,
@BOM DATE SELECT @BOM = DATE(20170401) SELECT @EOM = DATE(20170430) 
SELECT * FROM vPFS_CERNER_EOM_5A'
```

I have verified that my db connection is solid as I can exec non-stored procedure sql commands without issue.

Also this is the output from the SQL-log method

```
SQLReportController.php->apiRunReport results (0.0ms) DECLARE @EOM 
DATE, @BOM DATE SELECT @BOM = DATE(20170401) SELECT 
@EOM = DATE(20170430) SELECT * FROM vPFS_CERNER_EOM_5A
```

Figuring that maybe the @'s where screwing with the command I switched to single quotes to no avail. I also tried using the SQL->quote method which just caused sybase to puke with an error 102.

Perhaps I should post this to the fatfree git hub?